# Searching specific date from MongoDB Database and showing in jade file

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am requesting date,month and year from history.jade and searching date,month and year in database using flowing commands and showing the matched result in info.jade.

```
app.get('/info/chats',function(req, res){
var date = new Date(req.query.year, req.query.month, req.query.date);
chat.find({created : {$eq: date}}, function(err, docs){
  if(err) console.log(err);
  console.log("datefind");
  res.render('info',{users:docs});//Sending data to info page 
});
});
```

The problem is it is not searching the date which is matched.
Like if the var date =new Date(2015,06,05);
Then It should be searching this Date format: 2015-06-05T16:16:02.927Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a date range for your query; create a start and an end date objects that the date key should fall into. So, in your example to search for the date on the database with value `2015-06-05T16:16:02.927Z`, the start date should be `2015-06-05T00:00:00.000Z` and end should be `2015-06-06T00:00:00.000Z`:

```
app.get('/info/chats',function(req, res){
    var start = new Date(req.query.year, req.query.month-1, req.query.date),
        end   = new Date(req.query.year, req.query.month, req.query.date+1);

    chat.find({created : {$gte: start, $lt: end}}, function(err, docs){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        console.log("datefind");
        res.render('info', {users: docs}); //Sending data to info page 
    });
});
```